# regex to remove data between "some text (some text)"?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string in java which contains text as

```
Hello user your choice is in (1,2,3,4) as selected by you.
```

Now I want to remove `choice is in (1,2,3,4)` from this string with `""`.

I cannot directly do it using `replace()` in java as data inside the `()` is dynamic and changes every time.

**Output required**

```
Hello user your as selected by you.
```

I tried using regex but it failed and did not work, my regex

```
(?s)(\\choice is in .*?\\\\(\\\\)
```

Comment: String contains multiple occurrence of ). So can't do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
.replaceAll("\\s+choice\\s+is\\s+in\\s+\\([^()]*\\)", "")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CFt4nR/1).

- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `choice\s+is\s+in` - `choice is in` with any 1+ whitespaces in between words
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\([^()]*\)` - a `(`, then any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)`

See [Java demo](https://ideone.com/e8t3tP):

```
String s = "Hello user your choice is in (1,2,3,4) as selected by you.";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\s+choice\\s+is\\s+in\\s+\\([^()]*\\)", ""));
// => Hello user your as selected by you.
```

Answer (score 2):

Given below is a non-regex solution:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Hello user your choice is in (1,2,3,4) as selected by you.";
        int start = s.indexOf(" choice is in (");
        int end = s.indexOf(")", start);// Index of `)` after the index, `start`
        s = s.substring(0, start) + s.substring(end + 1);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello user your as selected by you.
```

Comment: Thanks @Arvind Kumar Avinash. This also helped me a lot.

Comment: Much better : )

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below code.

```
    String pattern = "choice is in (.*?) ";

    String userString = "Hello user your choice is in (1,2,3,4) as selected by you";
    userString = userString.replaceAll(pattern, "");
    System.out.println(userString);
```

Output will be :
Hello user your as selected by you

Comment: Why are you using a capture group? This will not work with: `blah choice is in (1, 2, 3, 4) blah`

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
    String pattern = "choice is in (.*) as";

    String userString = "Hello user your choice is in (1,2,3,4) as selected by you";
    userString = userString.replaceAll(pattern, "as");
    System.out.println(userString);
```

And the output would be:

```
Hello user your as selected by you
```

Comment: The output is [not as expected](https://ideone.com/FQXEgo), `Hello user your you`.

Comment: No it gives output as "Hello user your you"

Comment: I've edited the answer to remove the spaces problem. thanks for your notes.

Comment: @Sam See OP comment, *String contains multiple occurrence of `)`*. You can't use `(.*)`  here. Besides, the part after `in` must come inside literal parentheses.